# using lapply function and list in r

Tags: r, apply, lapply

```
d1 <- data.frame(col_one = c(1,2,3),col_two = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(col_one = c(1, 1, 1), col_two = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(col_one = c(7, 1, 1), col_two = c(8, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2,d3)

for (i in 1:3) {
  table<- lapply(my.list, function(data, count) {
    sql <-
      #sqldf(
        paste0(
          "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = ",
          count," group by col_one"
        )
      #)
    print(sql)
  },
  count = i)
}
```

output:

```
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
```

expectation:

```
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
```

How could I improve? I hope to run SQL to create a new dataset what I want but it is not successful and I can specify to know the index of the list which related to the SQL statement. Is there another simple method?

I have tried one of the methods.

```
d1 <- data.frame(col_one = c(1,2,3),col_two = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(col_one = c(3, 2, 1), col_two = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(col_one = c(7, 2, 1), col_two = c(8, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2,d3)
seq_along(x)
#for (i in 1:3) {
  table<- lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(index) {
    sql <-
      sqldf(
        paste0(
          "select *,count(col_one) from my.list where col_one = ",
          index," group by col_one"
        )
      )
    print(sql)
  })
#}
```

output:

```
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from my.list where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from my.list where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from my.list where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
```

however, it will not find the dataset to run SQL.

```
d1 <- data.frame(col_one = c(1,2,3),col_two = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(col_one = c(1, 1, 1), col_two = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(col_one = c(7, 1, 1), col_two = c(8, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2,d3)
table<- mapply(function(data, count) {
  sql <-
    sqldf(
    paste0(
      "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = ",
      count," group by col_one"
    )
  )
  print(sql)
}, my.list, 1
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind the rows of all the data frames together with additional columns for the index in `my.list` and the row count of each? `do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(i) cbind(Index = i, Count = nrow(my.list[[i]]), my.list[[i]])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the OP wants to create contingency tables for `col_one` for each of the data.frames in `my.list`, i.e., he wants to know how many times each of the values 1, 2, or 3 appear in `col_one` in each data.frame.

As explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48050780/3817004) to [another question of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48043372/3817004) and as suggested by [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846953/using-lapply-function-and-list-in-r#comment82661273_47846953), it is almost always better to combine data.frames with *identical structure* in a large data.table than to keep them separate in a list. BTW, there is also a third [question ("how to loop the dataframe using sqldf?")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48022642/3817004) by the OP asking for help with a list of data.frames.

To combine the data.frames in a large data.table, the `rbindlist()` function is used. Note that the added id column `df` identifies the originating data.frame of each row.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(my.list, idcol = "df")
```

> ```
>    df col_one col_two
> 1:  1       1       4
> 2:  1       2       5
> 3:  1       3       6
> 4:  2       1       6
> 5:  2       1       5
> 6:  2       1       4
> 7:  3       7       8
> 8:  3       1       5
> 9:  3       1       4
> ```

Now we can easily compute the aggregates:

```
rbindlist(my.list, idcol = "df")[, count_col_one := .N, by = .(df, col_one)][]
```

> ```
>    df col_one col_two count_col_one
> 1:  1       1       4             1
> 2:  1       2       5             1
> 3:  1       3       6             1
> 4:  2       1       6             3
> 5:  2       1       5             3
> 6:  2       1       4             3
> 7:  3       7       8             1
> 8:  3       1       5             2
> 9:  3       1       4             2
> ```

This `data.table` statement counts the occurrences of each individual value in `col_one` for each `df` by using the special symbol `.N` and by grouping by `df` and `col_one`.

In the question, the OP has only asked to count occurrences of 1, 2, or 3 in `col_one`. If this really is intended, the value of 7 needs to be removed. This can be accomplished by filtering the result:

```
rbindlist(my.list, idcol = "df")[, count_col_one := .N, by = .(df, col_one)][
  col_one %in% 1:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `data` and `counts` simultaneously. In `tidyverse` I would recommend using purrr::map2(), but in base R you can simply do:'

```
table<- mapply(function(data, count) {
    sql <-
      #sqldf(
      paste0(
        "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = ",
        count," group by col_one"
      )
    #)
    print(sql)
  }, my.list, 1:3
  )
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 1 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 2 group by col_one"
[1] "select *,count(col_one) from data where col_one = 3 group by col_one"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have learned the new function as I do not know that which keywords should I seek for.

How could I specify the index of the list which includes the related value? because the value is separated after running the SQL. For example, after running the SQL statement the first three item should be a list to save them together. I edit the content because I cannot format the code in the comment.  @dmi3kno

Comment: Not certain I understand what you mean. Could you, please, try to restate the question?

Comment: I edit the question, sorry for late as I'm thinking how to express the question. Could I  make each SQL statement to be a dataframe and make a list? Is it 2d list? I'm a beginner. @dmi3kno

Comment: oh, I have found the solution. Use SIMPLIFY = FALSE