# add missed value based on the value of the column in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

This is my sample dataset:

```
   vector1 <-
      data.frame(
        "name" = "a",
        "age" = 10,
        "fruit" = c("orange", "cherry", "apple"),
        "count" = c(1, 1, 1),
        "tag" = c(1, 1, 2)
      )
    vector2 <-
      data.frame(
        "name" = "b",
        "age" = 33,
        "fruit" = c("apple", "mango"),
        "count" = c(1, 1),
        "tag" = c(2, 2)
      )
    vector3 <-
      data.frame(
        "name" = "c",
        "age" = 58,
        "fruit" = c("cherry", "apple"),
        "count" = c(1, 1),
        "tag" = c(1, 1)
      )

    list <- list(vector1, vector2, vector3)
    print(list)
```

This is my test:

```
default <- c("cherry",
       "orange",
       "apple",
       "mango")

for (num in 1:length(list)) {
  #print(list[[num]])

  list[[num]] <- rbind(
    list[[num]],
    data.frame(
      "name" = list[[num]]$name,
      "age" = list[[num]]$age,
      "fruit" = setdiff(default, list[[num]]$fruit),#add missed value
      "count" = 0,
      "tag" = 1 #not found solutions
    )
  )

  print(paste0("--------------", num, "--------"))
  print(list)
}
#print(list)
```

I'm trying to find which fruit miss in the data frame and the fruit is based on the value of the tag.For example, in the first data frame, there are tags 1 and 2.If the value of tag 1 does not have the default fruit such as apple and banana, the missed default fruit will be added to 0 to the data frame.The expectation format likes the following:

```
[[1]]
  name age  fruit count tag
1    a  10 orange     1   1
2    a  10 cherry     1   1
3    a  10  apple     1   2
4    a  10  mango     0   1
5    a  10  apple     0   1
6    a  10  mango     0   2
7    a  10  orange    0   2
8    a  10  cherry    0   2
```

When I check the process of the loop, I also find that the first loop adds mango 3 times and I don't find the reason why it cannot add the missed value at one time.The overall output likes the following:

```
[[1]]
  name age  fruit count tag
1    a  10 orange     1   1
2    a  10 cherry     1   1
3    a  10  apple     1   2
4    a  10  mango     0   1
5    a  10  mango     0   1
6    a  10  mango     0   1

[[2]]
  name age  fruit count tag
1    b  33  apple     1   2
2    b  33  mango     1   2
3    b  33 cherry     0   1
4    b  33 orange     0   1

[[3]]
  name age  fruit count tag
1    c  58 cherry     1   1
2    c  58  apple     1   1
3    c  58 orange     0   1
4    c  58  mango     0   1
```

Does anyone help me and provides simple methods or other ways? Should I use the sqldf function to add 0 value?Is this a simple way to solve my problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). We can use `complete` to expand the data frame and specify the fill values as 0 to `count`.

Notice that I changed your list name from `list` to `fruit_list` because it is a bad practice to use reserved words in R to name an object. Also notice that when I created the example data frame I set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because I don't want to create factor columns. Finally, I used `lapply` instead of for-loop to loop through the list elements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fruit_list2 <- lapply(fruit_list, function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    complete(name, age, fruit = default, tag = c(1, 2), fill = list(count = 0)) %>%
    select(name, age, fruit, count, tag) %>%
    arrange(tag, fruit) %>%
    as.data.frame()
  return(x2)
})

fruit_list2
# [[1]]
#   name age  fruit count tag
# 1    a  10  apple     0   1
# 2    a  10 cherry     1   1
# 3    a  10  mango     0   1
# 4    a  10 orange     1   1
# 5    a  10  apple     1   2
# 6    a  10 cherry     0   2
# 7    a  10  mango     0   2
# 8    a  10 orange     0   2
# 
# [[2]]
#   name age  fruit count tag
# 1    b  33  apple     0   1
# 2    b  33 cherry     0   1
# 3    b  33  mango     0   1
# 4    b  33 orange     0   1
# 5    b  33  apple     1   2
# 6    b  33 cherry     0   2
# 7    b  33  mango     1   2
# 8    b  33 orange     0   2
# 
# [[3]]
#   name age  fruit count tag
# 1    c  58  apple     1   1
# 2    c  58 cherry     1   1
# 3    c  58  mango     0   1
# 4    c  58 orange     0   1
# 5    c  58  apple     0   2
# 6    c  58 cherry     0   2
# 7    c  58  mango     0   2
# 8    c  58 orange     0   2
```

**DATA**

```
vector1 <-
  data.frame(
    "name" = "a",
    "age" = 10,
    "fruit" = c("orange", "cherry", "apple"),
    "count" = c(1, 1, 1),
    "tag" = c(1, 1, 2),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
vector2 <-
  data.frame(
    "name" = "b",
    "age" = 33,
    "fruit" = c("apple", "mango"),
    "count" = c(1, 1),
    "tag" = c(2, 2),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
vector3 <-
  data.frame(
    "name" = "c",
    "age" = 58,
    "fruit" = c("cherry", "apple"),
    "count" = c(1, 1),
    "tag" = c(1, 1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

fruit_list <- list(vector1, vector2, vector3)

default <- c("cherry", "orange", "apple", "mango")
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.It is a faster way to fill the value to 0.
The value of tag 1 in list[[1]] is added mango but I also hope to add apple to 0 because it misses in tag 1.
Also, the value of fruit such as cherry, mango and orange misses in tag 2.How could I do it to add 0 and the value of different tags at the same time?

Comment: @hahakwok Please see y update. The `tag` now is part of the `complete` process.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions which you mentioned. I found it may be more suitable for me in a basic R. It's easy to learn. I also searched the function how to use as it's strange for me. 1. complete = complete the data frame with the missing combination of data
2. arrange = order the data frame by its columns.These are for other learning to see and I can review them. Could you also put the function which you write on the previous day? It's also useful to add 0 counts. Surely,I have saved

Comment: Sure. The choice between base R,` tidyverse`, or `data.table` sometimes is subjective. If base R is what you want, check Parfait's answer, and if that answer is useful, you can accept that one rather than my answer.

Comment: Your answer likes SQL. Surely, there're many different ways to do it.I find all of the answers are useful to learn too.

Comment: @hahakwok You can click the `edited 2 days ago` link on the bottom of the post to see previous edit records, but I think my current version is the good one because it is generating the right output, while my previous version does not generate the exact desired output.

Comment: Oh, thank you but it also useful if I meet the same problem. Now, I know the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Consider base R methods --`lapply`, `expand.grid`, `transform`, `rbind`, `aggregate`-- that appends all possible *fruit* and *tag* options to each dataframe and keeps the max counts.

```
new_list <- lapply(list, function(df) {
  fruit_tag_df <- transform(expand.grid(fruit=c("apple", "cherry", "mango", "orange"),
                                        tag=c(1,2)),
                            name = df$name[1],
                            age = df$age[1],
                            count = 0)

  aggregate(.~name + age + fruit + tag, rbind(df, fruit_tag_df), FUN=max)
})
```

**Output**

```
new_list

# [[1]]
#   name age  fruit tag count
# 1    a  10  apple   1     0
# 2    a  10 cherry   1     1
# 3    a  10 orange   1     1
# 4    a  10  mango   1     0
# 5    a  10  apple   2     1
# 6    a  10 cherry   2     0
# 7    a  10 orange   2     0
# 8    a  10  mango   2     0

# [[2]]
#   name age  fruit tag count
# 1    b  33  apple   1     0
# 2    b  33  mango   1     0
# 3    b  33 cherry   1     0
# 4    b  33 orange   1     0
# 5    b  33  apple   2     1
# 6    b  33  mango   2     1
# 7    b  33 cherry   2     0
# 8    b  33 orange   2     0

# [[3]]
#   name age  fruit tag count
# 1    c  58  apple   1     1
# 2    c  58 cherry   1     1
# 3    c  58  mango   1     0
# 4    c  58 orange   1     0
# 5    c  58  apple   2     0
# 6    c  58 cherry   2     0
# 7    c  58  mango   2     0
# 8    c  58 orange   2     0
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have searched some function.
1.expand.grid() creates a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors
2.transform() converts the first argument to a data frame.However, I do not deeply understand the aggregate function. Is it to join the data frame together? What the meaning of the max count when it put into aggregate?

Comment: Simply, `aggregate` is to remove the repeat groupings of *name, age, fruit, tag* that form with `merge` and passing `max` takes the highest (either zero or non-zero). If you know SQL, aggregate is similar to `group by` query and here the aggregation is `Max()`.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to complete each data.frame in `list` so that all combinations of `default` fruit and tags `1:2` will appear in the result whereby `count` should be set to `0` for the additional rows. Finally, each data.frame should consist at least of *4 x 2 = 8* rows.

I want to propose two different approaches:

1. Using `lapply()` and the `CJ()` (*cross join*) function from `data.table` to return a list.
2. Combine the separate data.frames in `list` to *one* large data.table using `rbindlist()` and apply the required transformations on the whole data.table.

#### Using `lapply()` and `CJ()`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(lst, function(x) setDT(x)[
  CJ(name = name, age = age, fruit = default, tag = 1:2, unique = TRUE), 
  on = .(name, age, fruit, tag)][
    is.na(count), count := 0][order(-count, tag)]
)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>    name age  fruit count tag
> 1:    a  10 cherry     1   1
> 2:    a  10 orange     1   1
> 3:    a  10  apple     1   2
> 4:    a  10  apple     0   1
> 5:    a  10  mango     0   1
> 6:    a  10 cherry     0   2
> 7:    a  10  mango     0   2
> 8:    a  10 orange     0   2
>
> [[2]]
>    name age  fruit count tag
> 1:    b  33  apple     1   2
> 2:    b  33  mango     1   2
> 3:    b  33  apple     0   1
> 4:    b  33 cherry     0   1
> 5:    b  33  mango     0   1
> 6:    b  33 orange     0   1
> 7:    b  33 cherry     0   2
> 8:    b  33 orange     0   2
>
> [[3]]
>    name age  fruit count tag
> 1:    c  58  apple     1   1
> 2:    c  58 cherry     1   1
> 3:    c  58  mango     0   1
> 4:    c  58 orange     0   1
> 5:    c  58  apple     0   2
> 6:    c  58 cherry     0   2
> 7:    c  58  mango     0   2
> 8:    c  58 orange     0   2
> ```

Ordering by `count` and `tag` is not required but helps to compare the result with OP's expected output.

#### Creating on large data.table

Instead of a list of data.frames with *identical structure* we can use one large data.table where the origin of each row can be identified by an id column.

Indeed, th OP has asked other questions (["using lapply function and list in r"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47846953/3817004)
 and ["how to loop the dataframe using sqldf?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48022642/3817004) where he asked for help in handling a list of data.frames. [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846953/using-lapply-function-and-list-in-r#comment82661273_47846953) already had suggested to `rbind` the rows together.

The `rbindlist()` function has the `idcol` parameter which identifies the origin of each row:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list, idcol = "df")
```

> ```
>    df name age  fruit count tag
> 1:  1    a  10 orange     1   1
> 2:  1    a  10 cherry     1   1
> 3:  1    a  10  apple     1   2
> 4:  2    b  33  apple     1   2
> 5:  2    b  33  mango     1   2
> 6:  3    c  58 cherry     1   1
> 7:  3    c  58  apple     1   1
> ```

Note that `df` contains the number of the source data.frame in `list` (or the names of the list elements if `list` is named).

Now, we can apply above solution by grouping over `df`:

```
rbindlist(list, idcol = "df")[, .SD[
  CJ(name = name, age = age, fruit = default, tag = 1:2, unique = TRUE), 
  on = .(name, age, fruit, tag)], by = df][
    is.na(count), count := 0][order(df, -count, tag)]
```

> ```
>     df name age  fruit count tag
>  1:  1    a  10 cherry     1   1
>  2:  1    a  10 orange     1   1
>  3:  1    a  10  apple     1   2
>  4:  1    a  10  apple     0   1
>  5:  1    a  10  mango     0   1
>  6:  1    a  10 cherry     0   2
>  7:  1    a  10  mango     0   2
>  8:  1    a  10 orange     0   2
>  9:  2    b  33  apple     1   2
> 10:  2    b  33  mango     1   2
> 11:  2    b  33  apple     0   1
> 12:  2    b  33 cherry     0   1
> 13:  2    b  33  mango     0   1
> 14:  2    b  33 orange     0   1
> 15:  2    b  33 cherry     0   2
> 16:  2    b  33 orange     0   2
> 17:  3    c  58  apple     1   1
> 18:  3    c  58 cherry     1   1
> 19:  3    c  58  mango     0   1
> 20:  3    c  58 orange     0   1
> 21:  3    c  58  apple     0   2
> 22:  3    c  58 cherry     0   2
> 23:  3    c  58  mango     0   2
> 24:  3    c  58 orange     0   2
>     df name age  fruit count tag
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used a huge table.